# How can I call two install4j launchers in sequence from one user app launch?

Tags: install4j

I have a tiny remote incremental update program (https://github.com/HitTheSticks/alamode), written in java, that needs to be launched before every execution of my main software (which is also written in java). It would be a bad idea to run the updater in the same process space as the main software, given that it's going to be stomping on all sorts of files that are pulled into the classpath by the main program.

Since the updater has basically no dependencies, I can simply generate a launcher with a safe context for it and run it before the main program.

But java's exec() facilities don't follow fork()/exec() semantics. Which means that for the updater to exec() the launcher will result in *both* JVMs running simultaneously, with all logging IO filtering through the updater. Yuck.

How can I make sure that when the user clicks [my start menu item], it always seamlessly runs [my updater]->[my program]?

I see 'com.install4j.api.launcher.ApplicationLauncher', but it doesn't specify whether or not the calling application can exit without also taking down the launched application. And preferably, I wouldn't nest the applications at all... I'd like them launched sequentially.

Oh, and it'd be cool if the solution were at least mostly portable.

Comment: There is no way to do this, especially not in a portable way. What is the problem if "my updater" still runs for a bit after it starts "my program"? It will already have updated the class path.

Comment: @IngoKegel The problem is that, as far as I can tell, [my updater] is responsible for draining stdout and stderr from its Runtime.exec() launch of [my program] forever. Is the install4j launcher redirect-to-file still going to work, or does the updater also have to do something intelligent with the output? It's also another instance of the JVM resident in memory.

Comment: the install4j redirect is still going to work regardless of how the executable was launched. The draining of stdout and stderr is not an issue if the parent process dies.